# Forcing a TK tree to fit in a window/canvas with scrollbar python 3.9

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a TK treeview that has quite a few columns that I simply wish to put in a LabelFrame with a horizontal scrollbar.  I have been through a ton of similar questions and nothing seems to be working.  In each case, the tree extends off the edge of the window along with the scrollbar.  I would like the displayed tree to fill the labelFrame, with a scrollbar at the bottom allowing the user to scroll left and right to view everything, and/or resize the window if their monitor is big enough.  For clarity, I will say that I do not care how wide the table is, so long as the user can scroll left and right within either the default or a resized window.

I cannot put every permutation I've tried here, but this is a minimal example.  I have tried with and without a canvas (though I believe I was doing that incorrectly), putting in a LabelFrame, pack_propagate(0), ordering the grid commands, etc.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

#mainWindow is the primary form, this is a secondary window

recentWindow = tk.Tk() #replace the line below to run without mainWindow and add
#mainWindow.mainloop()

#recentWindow = tk.TopLevel(mainWindow)
recentWindow.geometry('800x300')

frmtreeborder = tk.LabelFrame(recentWindow,text='Recent')
recentWindow.pack_propagate(0) #added later for testing, tried with frmtreeborder too
#also tried grid_propagate

#Tried putting the grid statements below for everything but the tree here
#Also tried moving the scrollbar definition here
tree = ttk.Treeview(frmtreeborder,columns=colnames,show='headings',
    height=5,selectmode='extended')

#Populate a colnames just for the example to run
colnames = []
for ii in range(0,20):
    colnames.append(str(ii))
    
for a in colnames:
    tree.column(a,width=85)
    tree.heading(a,text=a)

frmtreeborder.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew',padx=6,pady=6)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(recentWindow,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=tree.xview)
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='nw') #if 'new' the scrollbar is the same width as the tree
#Also moved the scrollbar outside the labelFrame to see if that helped
tree.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew',padx=6,pady=6) #also tried pack
```

The resulting window.  What is not shown is that if the scrollbar is given sticky='nsew' it is the same width as the tree.  This makes sense in retrospect, though it implies that everything is dynamically resized since order doesn't seem to matter.  I'll note that I am a bit in the Monte Carlo regime of testing, so I may have muddled something up during that process. [image: resulting window]

Running python 3.9.7 (Anaconda)

Some unsuccessful threads:

[tkinter fixed canvas size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669264/tkinter-fixed-canvas-size?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Python Treeview scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877848/python-treeview-scrollbar)

[tkinter ttk treeview...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577363/tkinter-ttk-treeview-how-to-set-fixed-width-why-it-change-with-number-of-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` on both `recentWindow` and `frmtreeborder` so that the size of `frmtreeborder` and `tree` are bound by the size of their parent container.

Also use `sticky='ew'` instead of `sticky='nw'` on the scrollbar.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

recentWindow = tk.Tk()
recentWindow.geometry('800x300')

recentWindow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
recentWindow.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frmtreeborder = tk.LabelFrame(recentWindow,text='Recent')

frmtreeborder.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frmtreeborder.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

colnames = [str(ii) for ii in range(20)]
tree = ttk.Treeview(frmtreeborder,columns=colnames,show='headings',
                    height=5,selectmode='extended')

for a in colnames:
    tree.column(a,width=85)
    tree.heading(a,text=a)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(recentWindow,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=tree.xview)
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frmtreeborder.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew',padx=6,pady=6)
tree.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew',padx=6,pady=6)
scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ew')

recentWindow.mainloop()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This successfully solved the issue.  Thank you!  For others who may want to read more about row and columnconfigure: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/ and a nice summary of what they are doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter